# Proof question related to Bolzano-Weierstrass property

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose that $I ⊂ R$ is closed and bounded, and hence has the Bolzano-Weierstrass property .
 Also assume that a particular δa > 0 is associated with each a ∈ I. Use a proof by contradiction to show that there must exist a particular $n ∈N$ such that $∀x ∈ I ∃a ∈ I (x− 1/n,x + 1/n) ⊂ (a−δa,a + δa)$.

A hint says: if you assume this is not true, you get a statement that must hold for all n ∈ N, so you should be able to generate a sequence indexed by n to which you can apply the BWP ...]

But I cannot be so sure that where should I start the proof and how exactly should I choose the sequence?

Could someone please give a full proof or give some hint on:
1.What is the original sequence?

2.What is the convergent subsequence we need?

3.How the obtain the sequence?

4.What contradiction will we come up with?

And the question also has another question followed, so I guess maybe there is something related with uniform continuity.

The question is:prove that, if $I ⊂R$ is closed and bounded, then a continuous function $f : I →R$ must be uniformly continuous.

Many thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is true... Consider $I = [0,1]$, $\delta a = .5$ for each $a \in [0,1]$,and $x = 0$. Then the smallest $n$ you can find is $1$ but $[-1,1]$ is not contained in any $\delta a$ interval around $a$.

Comment: @mathworker21 I think it cannot be a false statement because $\delta a$ is related to a. i.e. we get an $a$ first, then $\delta a$.

Comment: You can choose $\delta a = .5$ for each $a$. You didn't give any property of $\delta a$.

Comment: @mathworker21 I am so sorry of the mistake in typing!!! There is $1$ over$n$ in the statement, not $1n$.

Comment: that makes much more sense! thanks :)  now we want $n$ large.

Comment: @mathworker21 Yes and actually I can hardly go further and stuck on here. I haven't reach anything related to BWP so far. But it is exactly an exercise of practicing BWP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the statement is false. Then, for all $n \ge 1$, there is some $x_n \in I$ such that $\forall a \in I$, $(x_n-\frac{1}{n},x_n+\frac{1}{n}) \not \subseteq (a-\delta_a,a+\delta_a)$. Conceptually, what's going on here, is that the $\delta$ associated with the $x_n$'s are too small (smaller than $\frac{1}{n}$), and the delta's of the points nearby $x_n$ are too small. We use the sequence $(x_n)$ for BWP. Take a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})$, converging say to $x^*$. Let $\delta_* = \delta_{x^*}$.

We get the contradiction by showing that for a large enough $n$, $(x_n-\frac{1}{n},x_n+\frac{1}{n}) \subseteq (x^*-\delta_*,x^*+\delta_*)$. To show this, we can just choose $n$ large enough so that $|x^*-x_n| < \delta_*/2$ and so that $\frac{1}{n} < \delta_*/2$.

You should think more about the connection of this problem with uniform continuity now that you see the proof of the first part. Hints: The $\delta_a$'s corresponding to each $a$ correspond to the $\delta$ neighborhood of $a$ that maps into the $\epsilon$ neighborhood of $f(x)$, in the definition of uniform continuity. The "universal" nature of $n$ played here gets you uniform continuity.

Comment: Could you please give more explaination on the statement:", we can just choose nn large enough so that |x∗−xn|<δ∗/2,and so that 1/n<δ∗/2."? i.e. why the first inequality implies the second one? Is it because of we can choose n large enough to get  |x∗−xn|<1/n<δ∗/2? But it seems that when we enlarge n, 1/n becomes even smaller so we cannot ensure if there exist an n such that  |x∗−xn|<1/n.

Comment: I agree that |x∗−xn|<δ∗/2 can hold because of the convergence. But how does it imply 1/n<δ∗/2?

Comment: We are choosing $n$ large enough so that both of those hold. The first does not imply the second.

Comment: You can think about the implication of these two inequalities geometrically (on the real line) to see that they do indeed imply $(x_n-\frac{1}{n},x_n+\frac{1}{n} \subseteq (x^*-\delta_*,x^*+\delta_*)$. Or of course, you can work it out algebraically.

Comment: Oh, I see. Clear answer! Many thanks!